# Problema con pilas en java

Tags: java, poo, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo que hacer un metodo que copia el contenido de una pila(llamemosla A) en otra pila(llamemosla B) , ese metodo ademas debe retornar B , y no puedo eliminar ningun elemento de A,ademas si a A se le añade un nuevo elemento , no afectara al contenido de B , ¿es esto posible?

Los metodos que puedo utilizar son:

```
 public void apilar(int dato) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(dato, cima);
    cima = nuevo;
      // O bien: cima = new NodoLE(dato, cima)
    numElementos++;
}

public int desapilar() {
    int valor;
    if (this.vacia()) {
        System.out.println("Error, la pila está vacía");
        valor = -9999;
    } else {
        valor = cima.getDato();
        cima = cima.getSiguiente();
        numElementos--;
    }
    return valor;
}

public int getCima() {
    int valor;
    if (this.vacia()) {
        System.out.println("Error, la pila está vacía");
        valor = -9999;
    } else {
        valor = cima.getDato();
    }
    return valor;
}

public void quitarCima() {
    if (this.vacia()) {
        System.out.println("Error, la pila está vacía");
    } else {
        cima = cima.getSiguiente();
        numElementos--;
    }
}

public int getNumElementos() {
    return numElementos;
}

public void mostrar() {
    Nodo aux = cima;
    System.out.println("Contenido de la pila:");
    while (aux != null) {
        System.out.println(aux.getDato());
        aux = aux.getSiguiente();
    }
    System.out.println("FIN");
}
```

Comment: Si es una pila debes "eliminar" (pop) almenos temporalmente lo que este en la cima de A para leer lo que esta abajo, ¿Tal vez te refieres a dejar A como estaba?

Comment: A fuerzas tienes que usar Nodo como tipo de dato? o puedes utilizar otro

Comment: Me quede esperando el problema. ¿Cuál es tu duda?

Comment: @YeisonA si exactamente es lo que tengo que hacer copiarla , pero dejarla igual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fuerzas tienes que usar tu variable Nodo?

Mira con Queue Puedes hacer esto espero que te sirva de ejemplo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue A = new LinkedList();


    A.add("1");
    A.add("2");
    A.add("3");
    A.add("4");

    Queue B = GetB(A);

}

public static Queue GetB(Queue A){
    Queue B = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        B.add(A.toArray()[i]);
    }

    return B;
}
```